# Event not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form in which i have a text box for email and many other textboxes.
The email has a functionality that it should not match with previously entered email but it can be blank.

I fired my code at the text change event of the textbox and it is working fine.
But when i click on the update button without taking my cursor off the textbox.
The click of the button is not working.Only textchanged event of textbox fires nothing else happen.

Please help me with the same.

```
 string emailid = txtemail.Text;
var emailcnt2 = (from r in context.Customers
                                 where r.Email == Convert.ToString(emailid)
                                 select r).SingleOrDefault();

                if (emailcnt2 != null)
                {
                    lblemail.Text = "Email already exists for customer " + emailcnt2.FirstName + " " + emailcnt2.LastName + "";
                    //  emaildisplay.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
                    txtemail.Focus();
                }
```

Comment: please provide code which demonstrates the problem

Comment: @AndrasZoltan i have written the code of text change event

Comment: button click doesnot fire....only the text change gets fir

Comment: I don't think the code is needed, the problem is simple (and known): the OnClick  doesn't fire when AutoPostBack is true for TextBox (actually it fires TextChanged instead of the Click event)

Comment: @AdrianIftode exactly....and i want a solution for that

Comment: I had this issue me too about an year ago, I'm trying to find how I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked on project where I had this issue and the "hack" was to put the textbox inside an `UpdatePanel`, it seems it works in most of the cases ( I had tests when the button click didn't fire, but they were few, actually very rare).

I can't tell exactly why it works, I don't have a certain or valid explanation, but probably is because the UpdatePanel makes its own request, while the form submit it's just another request.

Going further, I'm trying to think to an explanation of this behavior. It seems the TextChanged event is really firing when the text is changed (hilarious, no?). We expect this event to fire at onblur moment, if it's the case, ie the text changed, but when some other button is clicked, probably the javascript generated by ASP .Net checks if the text is changed and then submits the form to fire this event. The button click is lost now, because a form cannot be submitted twice.

Now, what UpdatePanel brings is that it has the responsibility to fire the TextChanged event, so the button click is now fired as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is fire the textChanged event also when pressing the button.

I would put all the textChanged event logic into a method ValidateTextBoxes, and call it in the textbox textChanged event and in the button click event separately.

Let me know if I misunderstood you.

Edit:
I didn't understand the problem at hand.
See comments.

Comment: I want textchange and button to fire at the same moment........wheni press the button...only text change fires and not the button click

Comment: Register your button click event to an OnClick method with an appropriate signature, and in there call the ValidateTextBoxes and add button-click logic.

Comment: Sounds to me as if your button has no event listeners, or you listen to his click event using the textChanged method. Double click the button to listen to it's click event and fill in logic in the method it creates for you called something like button1_onClick.

Comment: @Abhishek: Yorye Nathan is right, you should encapsulate the functionality into methods that can be called from wherever you want. Then you don't need to "fire" both events since the resulting action would be the same anyway, so no need to do things twice. By the way, you don't need the AutoPostBack on the TextBox if you have a button anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are right but then the validation for email would be on the button click and anyone would have to click it again and again to see that the email matches or not....that would look ugly

Comment: @Abhishek You will still have the Validate method called on textChanged, but the button will have to check the Validate by itself too to make sure it can continue (or have Validate save last result in some data member and have the button logic check for that)

Comment: @Abhishek: Whenever user clicks `ENTER` in the TextBox, the form's default button will be clicked. You can put it into an ASP.NET Panel and set it's [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property to your update-button. That might be sufficient for you and your users.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Make the user press enter to validate strings are the same?! I would either listen to textChanged or to lostFocus.

Comment: @YoryeNathan this would not work out the way i want it.....when i would click the button and my cursor is on the same textbox where i fired the textchange event then the button click event would not be called at all

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Most users have meanwhile realized that a WebApplication is something other than a Winforms-App. They are used to click a button to submit changes to the server. That said, you'd support even more convenience by let the user confirm their changes by hitting `ENTER` and auto-submit them afterwards.

Comment: @Abhishek It will if you register the button click event to a new onClick method... The button doesn't care whether the cursor is on a different control or not - it has been clicked! Are you telling me that this works for you when you first tab focus into the button and then click it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree to that, but I'm suggesting only addition validation checks. Enter will indeed validate and submit of validated true, but I suggest letting the user validate (at least some of the information) client-sided before sending out the form.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i want to check database information so doing it at the clientside is not possible

Comment: @Abhishek: What i've sugested is not clientside but trigger the update-button via enter-click when the textbox has focus. But you can always call the update-functionality from your TextChanged-Event when it passes the validation check. On this way you can keep your AutoPostback on the TextBox.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry, I thought there were two email text boxes, for matching vaildation. In case of database checking, of course, only check when submitting form.

Comment: @Abhishek He can also have a CheckEmail button which will be clicked when enter is clicked + email textbox had focus, which will only validate the mail, so not the whole form will be validated for nothing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but it is not every time that i whenever the validation is true i want it to update....it is an altogether different possiblities of a case